# Off-PaaS development environment for OpenShift

Tags: openshift

I would like to deploy an application to OpenShift. The application itself does not require much resources, so it could live perfectly happily in a small gear.

However, it links to some libraries that are not available on OpenShift, and I need to compile them from source. They are written in C++, and compiling C++ requires a lot of memory it seems, and the compilation fails.

What is the suggested solution to this? Can I just compile it offline, on an identical system? What is an identical system? Or should I compile it in a bigger gear, and then copy it over to the small gear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to compile your c++ application on another binary compatible system (centos, or another RHEL install) and then just upload the binaries to your gear, keeping in mind that you need to make sure that all of the dependencies are there etc.

Comment: Thanks! To have a complete answer, you can check the CentOS/RHEL version you need via `cat /etc/redhat-release`. Right now this is release 6.5.